# If programatically switch on bluetooth then user should not switch off bluetooth in android mobile

Tags: android, bluetooth

User should not able to switch off Bluetooth using device.Actualy I am implementing MDM for this if i am going to switch off bluetooth from background programatically then user could not switch on bluetooth from device.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Have you attempted to do this and encountered a problem? Although I'm not sure how the android system would feel about you locking the user out of their own system

Comment: I think this is not possible..

Comment: Anurag I think Android is designed to make sure the user can overwrite what an application does at any time. Most you could do is have a background thread with the right permissions turn bluetooth off every minute or so. But that's hackish at best and error prone at best.

Comment: Hi Richard if I am programatically swicth On bluetooth but user can switch off it from the device .I need permanently switch off when i install my MDM .

Comment: Ya Ewit but same thing already implemented by SAMSUNG (mass360).But i do not have any Anroid API for doing this .is there any third party library